# How many terms of the series $-12,-9,-6\ldots$ must be taken so that the sum may be $54$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

My attempt: we need to find $n$ given here
$a = -12$,
$d = 3$,
sum $= 54$,

so ,
$${n\over 2}( 2a + (n-1)d ) = 54$$
$${n\over 2}(2 \cdot (-12) + (n-1)3 ) =54$$
$${n\over 2}(-24 + 3n - 3) = 54$$
$${n\over 2}(-27 + 3n ) = 54$$
$$-27n + 3n^2 = 108$$

I am stuck here.

Comment: Why stuck. Easy quadratic.

Comment: It's a quadratic equation. If you solve it, you'll get $n=-3$ or $n=12$ so only the second one makes sense in this case. The quadratic in question is $3n²-27n-108=0$.

Comment: ok so i have to use quadratic formula ?

Comment: any other way other than using the formula like dividing with 3 both sides ?

Comment: Alternatively just keep adding until you reach $54$.  Then count the terms and note that adding any more positive terms will give a sum that is too large

Answer (score 2):

It seems the OP is seeking the shortest method to solve this math puzzle. Here is a short-cut.

Take a look at te first 9 terms: $-12, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9,12$. It is clear that all terms cancel so their sum is equal to zero.

Now add a few additional terms ($15, 18, 21$) and you have reached the total of $54$.

Answer (score 1):

We can continue from this point:

$$-27n + 3n^2 = 108$$

We want to turn this to this form that has a known solution formula:

$$An^{2}+Bn+C=0$$

Add (-108) to both sides:

$$-27n + 3n^2 -108=0$$

Arrange the terms according to powers of $(n)$:

$$3n^{2}-27n-108=0$$

Divide both sides by $(3)$ to simplify the looks (optional):

$$n^{2}-9n-36=0$$

The general solution(s) for the quadratic equation are:

$$n=\left(\frac{-B+\sqrt{\left(B^2-4AC\right)}}{2A}\right)\:And,\:Or\:n=\left(\frac{-B-\sqrt{\left(B^2-4AC\right)}}{2A}\right)$$

We should get 1 solution only in our case, it can't be negative because its a count.

In our case: $A=1$ and $B=-9$ and $C=-36$

The correct answer is $12$.

The $12$ terms would be:
$$-12, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21$$

Comment: is this the shortest method to solve from where i left off ? because i have  exam in the coming months where i have to solve such questions under a min , if there is any other shortcuts from where i left off please tell me .

Comment: You stopped at solving the quadratic equation. I have added the steps in some detail. As soon as you construct the quadratic equation, sometimes the solution is clear and the formula is not needed. But if you can't "guess" the roots, you should resort to the formula. Also, it may help to know that $\left(x+r_1\right)\left(x+r_2\right)=x^2+\left(r_1+r_2\right)x+\left(r_1r_2\right)$ - This may help you figure the roots without the formula.

Comment: If you are allowed to use a graphing device, plotting the graph of the quadratic will show the roots immediately of course.